# VAT error on promotion Zero-1 - Buy X get the cheapest free

Tags: promotions

we have an ongoing problem with using the Zero-1 - Buy X get the cheapest free promotion.
We have it set across a range of products on 4+1, it works great when the customer orders, say, 3 of 1 item and 2 of another. However, when the customer orders 5 of the same product, Magento minuses the cost of the item inc. VAT (all of our products are listed ex VAT) before VAT is added, thus giving them an extra discount as well as the product free.
[image: magento error at chefckout]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try to update the discount tax settings as at the screen:
[image: discount-tax]

Comment: Thank you but they were already set to that. This only happens when they order all of the same product on offer. it doesn't happen if they order a selection of items on the offer.

Comment: Can you reproduce it on a fresh magento without extensions?  What are your tax settings?

Comment: I've added an image of them onto the original question as can't see how to do it in the comments. I can't reproduce on fresh magento but could ask my developers to if that might help? They were unable to resolve the issue for me, told me it was a quirk we would have to put up with...

Comment: So the source of the issue probably in some custom module. It's very hard to guess what it could be, so your dev can disable all extensions and then enable them one by one to find which one has the bug.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will ask them to do this over the next week.